# Angular - 2 components with same URL

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I have a requirement where I need to use the same URL for 2 components.

Let's assume that the path is `/path` and the components are `Foo` and `Bar`.

Initially, I will see the Foo component and after pressing a link I will be redirected to the Bar component.

```
/path (Foo) => /path (Bar)
```

Now I see the Bar component and if I press the back button from the browser I need to be redirected to the Foo component

```
/path (Bar) =>back button=>/path (Foo)
```

And also if I press the "forward" button I need to see the Bar component

```
/path (Foo) =>forward button=> /path (Bar)
```

So, basically, I need to have the same URL but somehow keep all the features provided by the Angular router, just as if there were 2 different paths.

Is this possible? I've looked into the NavigationExtras options, like `skipLocationChange`, or `replaceUrl` but these options don't help me. Neither does `history` `pushState` or `replaceState` (or maybe I don't know how to make use of them).

Comment: Ultimately I don't think it's possible to use the browser back / fwd buttons without making some change to the URL... And even if you could work something out, I don't know if it would be a good idea... Have updated my answer with one approach and some example code. I think you might need to be satisfied with the same path, but adding a query param to indicate which component should be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you'd be better off having one parent component with one url path, which contains the components `foo` and `bar`, and conditionally displays one or the other, depending on a query parameter in the URL. e.g.

```
toggleFooBar(){
    this.showFoo = !this.showFoo;
    this.router.navigate([], 
        {
            relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
            queryParams: {showFoo : this.showFoo}
        }
    );
}
```

More info about url params [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-required-or-optional).

If you subscribe to changes in location in your parent component (and show / hide `foo` or `bar` accordingly), the forward and back buttons should work as required:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.location.subscribe(queryParams => {
        // Don't forget to unsubscribe on destroy
        this.showFoo = (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams.showFoo !== 'true')
    });
}
```

Live example with code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w1w88g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts), but use this to see the [forward / back buttons in action](https://angular-w1w88g.stackblitz.io).

I don't think you're going to be able to use the forward / back buttons without some change to the URL, because the URL has to change in order for there to be entries in the browser history to go back or forward through.

It might be possible to get close with some serious code gymnastics... maybe you could use the query parameters and then take them off again? But even then, I think you'd be at risk of causing the browser / history to behave in unexpected ways, which will likely to more harm than good to your application.